# Use variables inside @component styles

Tags: angular, components

I want to generate some dynamic CSS and use it inside the styles of @component. I don't know exactly how to pass that variable and wonder even if it is possible to do this.
Here is the piece of code that uses the variable "stylesArray".

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    styles: stylesArray,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent {
    stylesArray: string[] = [
        // Generate some dynamic css here
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the host decorator property:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    host: {
      '[style]': 'stylesArray'
    }
})
export class AppComponent {
    stylesArray: string = [
        // Generate some dynamic css here
        // for example:
        'display: block; background: red;'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But it will threw error on runtime `error NG1010: Decorator host metadata must be an object. Value could not be determined statically.`
Also the [style] attribute only accepts expression as string and not Array.

Comment: yep, sorry, forgot quotes :)

Comment: That didn't work for me unfortunately. I didn't have errors or something. I wish this answer has an example of how exactly stylesArray would look like.

Comment: @William add example to the answer